# Row wise element search in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector ( say `v = (1, 5, 7)` ) and an array.

```
 a = [ [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6], 
       [7, 8, 9] ]
```

What would be the most efficient way to find indices of elements in vector v in the corresponding row in a. For example, the output here would  be 
`b  = (0, 1, 0)` since `1` is at the `0th` index in 1st row and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert `v` to a column vector with `[:,None]` and then compare with `a` to bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and finally use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to get the final output as indices -

```
np.where(a == v[:,None])[1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [34]: a
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [35]: v
Out[35]: array([1, 5, 7])

In [36]: np.where(a == v[:,None])[1]
Out[36]: array([0, 1, 0])
```

In case, there are multiple elements in a row in `a` that match the corresponding element from `v`, you can use [`np.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) to get indices of the first match in each row, like so -

```
np.argmax(a == v[:,None],axis=1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [57]: a
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 7]])

In [58]: v
Out[58]: array([1, 5, 7])

In [59]: np.argmax(a == v[:,None],axis=1)
Out[59]: array([0, 1, 0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> v = (1, 5, 7)
>>> b = tuple([a[id].index(val) for id, val in enumerate(v)])
>>> b
(0, 1, 0)
```

Comment: Or  `tuple(i.index(j) for i,j in zip(a,v))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[a[idx].index(val) for idx, val in enumerate(v)]
```

Where [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an iterable of index and the value itself, and [index](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) returns the index of the first apperance of `val` in the correct row.

If you must get a tuple as the return value convert it in the end:

```
b = tuple([a[idx].index(val) for idx, val in enumerate(v)])
```

Just note that index may raise ValueError if `val` wasn't found in the correct row of `a`.

Comment: nice job. add tuple to match output format                               tuple([a[idx].index(val) for idx, val in enumerate(v)])